# Any idea about module in KNeighborsClassifier module <fit>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn, ipython

I have a project for my exam about Machine Learning.
What i expected is 1 as yes or 0 as no as output from these dataset.

```
MinTemp=[8,14,13.7,13.3,7.6,6.2,6.1,8.3,8.8,8.4]
MaxTemp=[24.3,26.9,23.4,15.5,16.1,16.9,18.2,17,19.5,22.8]
Rainfall=[0,3.6,3.6,39.8,2.8,0,0.2,0,0,16.2]
WindGustDir=[315,67.5,315,315,157.5,135,135,90,180,90]
RISK_MM=[3.6,3.6,39.8,2.8,0,0.2,0,0,16.2,0]
RainTomorrow=[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]

from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

MinTemp_encoded = le.fit_transform(MinTemp)
MaxTemp_encoded = le.fit_transform(MaxTemp)
Rainfall_encoded = le.fit_transform(Rainfall)
WindGustDir_encoded = le.fit_transform(WindGustDir)
RISK_MM_encoded = le.fit_transform(RISK_MM)
label = le.fit_transform(RainTomorrow)

 features=list(zip(MinTemp_encoded,MaxTemp_encoded,Rainfall_encoded,WindGustDir_encoded,RISK_MM_encoded))

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)

model.fit(features,label)

predicted = model.predict([[0,2]])
print(predicted)
```

I expect the output is 1 or 0. But this is error-code from terminal when I execute "python readyToTest.py"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readyToTest.py", line 28, in <module>
    predicted = model.predict([[0,2]])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py", line 145, in predict
    neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 353, in kneighbors
    n_jobs=n_jobs, squared=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1235, in pairwise_distances
    return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1078, in _parallel_pairwise
    return func(X, Y, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 222, in euclidean_distances
    X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 122, in check_pairwise_arrays
    X.shape[1], Y.shape[1]))
ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 2 while Y.shape[1] == 5
```

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: in your fit method, you have 5 features, and in your predict method you only use 3 features (column 0-2), you have to adjust it and use the same amount of features

Comment: Thanks for the answer! trying now

Comment: it should be model.predict([[8,24,0,315,3.6]])